# MySQL - Can you retrieve the default value of a column?

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, default

I was looking at creating a TRIGGER that will set the value of a column to its DEFAULT if the INSERT value happens to be an empty string.

My TRIGGER looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER column_a_to_default 
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.a = '' THEN
SET NEW.a = 'some value';
END IF;
END
```

I would like to know if I can replace 'some value' with a way to set it to the DEFAULT value of the column. i.e.

```
SET NEW.a = a.DEFAULT
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you

```
SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(NEW.a)
```

EDIT:
It looks like that doesn't work.

Use this workaround

```
IF NEW.a = '' THEN
   SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
   WHERE
     table_schema = 'database_name'
     AND table_name = 'your_table'
     AND column_name = 'a';
   SET NEW.a = @def;
END IF;
```

You can also try

```
SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(table_name.a)
```

Comment: Wow, I searched around and couldn't find anything and pseudo code was really close.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this is creating a warning of "Column 'a' cannot be null" if the supplied value matches the IF statement in the TRIGGER.

Comment: Or better `DEFAULT(a)`. See the documentation: MySQL's [`DEFAULT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_default) function.

Comment: I'm getting a new error "Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'".  I'm checking for an empty string and want to supply the column's DEFAULT. My INSERT looks like this: `INSERT INTO table ( a, b, c ) VALUES ( '', 'two', 'three' )`

Comment: I am sorry I forgot the `NEW.` at the `a`. See my update and try again.

Comment: I just tried that.  I now get and error "Field 'a' doesn't have a default value".  But it does, I double checked.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can provide your table structure and trigger on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: Having trouble building the schema for the trigger

Comment: Did you change the Server version in the combobox in the upper left corner to MySQL? Post the link and I will have a look.

Comment: @hungerstar: I re-asked your question in a more specific way. See here for the solution: [mysql-trigger-doesnt-know-default-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818956/)

Comment: @hungerstar: I updated it. Could you also try `SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(table_name.a)`? I think that works.

Comment: Using `SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(table_name.a)` creates an error "Unknown table 'table_name' in field list".  The solution with `SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def` in it works.  Thanks!