# MySQL Trigger doesn't know default value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, default-value

I use this trigger

```
delimiter ||
create TRIGGER column_a_to_default 
BEFORE INSERT ON `property`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
  IF NEW.primary_image = '' THEN
    SET NEW.primary_image = default(NEW.primary_image);
  END IF;
END;
||
delimiter ;
```

If I insert into the table the trigger throws an error:

> Field 'primary_image' doesn't have a default value.

But it does!

What is wrong here? It seems like the trigger isn't aware of default values!

### EDIT

Table Create script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `images` text NOT NULL,
  `primary_image` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '../no-image.png',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement used. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `default(property.primary_image)` work? *(Getting the default of the Real table, not the NEW holding-table)*

Comment: @Dems: You are right. It does work. Post it as answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't `default(property.primary_image)` work?

*(Getting the default of the Real table, not the NEW holding-table)*

Comment: Really. It works. I had tried this too, but somehow it did not work for me. Anyway +1.

Comment: @Devart - I think you guys were trying `default(NEW.primary_image)`, but the `NEW` table isn't that `property` table.  It's just a similar table, with only what is necessary to log the changes.  Querying `property` directly ensures you get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow it does not work.

Try this workaround -

```
  IF NEW.primary_image = '' THEN
    SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def
      FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE
      table_schema = 'database_name'
      AND table_name = 'property'
      AND column_name = 'primary_image';
    SET NEW.primary_image = @def;
  END IF;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. Error: `Column primary_image cannot be null`. Seems like it can't get the default value this way either.

Comment: INSERT INTO property (primary_image) VALUES (''); should work

Comment: I am sorry. It worked. I forgot to replace the `database_name` string. Thank you very much!