# How to get column's DEFAULT in trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers, default

I'd like one column's value to be forced to DEFAULT in trigger by some conditions.
In example below, if `b` IS NULL, `a` should be set with defined DEFAULT (that is 'SYSTEM').

```
CREATE TABLE `t_default` (
      `n` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    , `a` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'SYSTEM'
    , `b` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL
    -- To moderators: please do not edit my formatting :)
);

DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_t_default_BeforeInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `t_default` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.b IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(a);
    END IF;
END
//

DELIMITER ;
```

Unfortunately, this gives error message "**Unknown column 'a' in 'field list'**" on insert:

```
INSERT INTO t_default (n) VALUES ('1');
```

I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818956/mysql-trigger-doesnt-know-default-value), however providing table name or db + table name does not work as well:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_t_default_BeforeInsert` BEFORE INSERT ON `t_default` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.b IS NULL THEN
        SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(t_default.a);
        -- SET NEW.a = DEFAULT(test.t_default.a);
    END IF;
END
```

In this case message is slightly different: "**Unknown table 't_default' in field list**"

Also, I tried to use back quotes around column name with no success.

So, is it possible to get column DEFAULT in trigger at all? I'm using MySQL 5.7.

Thanks.

P.S. Sure, I know that I can do `SET NEW.a = 'SYSTEM';`

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
IF NEW.b IS NULL THEN
    SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
    WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' 
                       AND table_name = 't_default' 
                       AND column_name = 'a'; 
SET NEW.a = @def; 
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for the example where DEFAULT is string. Does not work if it is expression (`a DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for example).

Comment: @fifonik, are you getting any error for `Datetime`? Or not getting values?

Comment: "Incorrect datetime value 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for column 'a'..."

Comment: @fifonik You can use `IF (NEW.b IS NULL) THEN 
        SET NEW.a = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    END IF;` for date columns