# Set default value if empty string is passed

Tags: mysql, schema

I am trying to find a solution to achieve the following result.

If MySQL query has empty string `''`, than use default value defined in a table schema.

For example

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`name`,`nickname`,`balance`) 
VALUES ('hello','world','');
```

In this case if the balance column's default value is `0` then it should be set instead of the empty string.

Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to create a trigger. Read more about the triggers on [Mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html). Similar answer for more details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9817632/mysql-can-you-retrieve-the-default-value-of-a-column).

For this question here is my implementation of the trigger.

```
delimiter #
create trigger nonEmptyString
before insert
on users
for each row

BEGIN
IF NEW.balance = '' THEN
   SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
   WHERE
     table_schema = 'Schema Name'
     AND table_name = 'users'
     AND column_name = 'balance';
   SET NEW.balance = @def;
END IF;

end#

delimiter ;
```

> Note : Replace **Schema Name**  with the name of your schema.

Comment: You can use the [DATABASE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_database) function instead of `Schema Name`.

Answer (score 0):

use a variable (such as $balance) instead of '' (which I expect you'd be doing anyway).

On the line before your query:

```
if(strlen(trim($balance))==0){ $balance='0'; }
```

You could also use the mysql case syntax, which is a bit clunky, but very much on point for your description.

[MySQL update CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754470/mysql-update-case-when-then-else)